# QHBoxLayout addwidget() order and two qglwidget share texture object

Tags: qt, opengl, textures, qglwidget

I created two `QGLwidget` objects:

```
slicerCanvas* slicerX_;
secCan* secWid_;
secWid_ = new secCan(this);

//slicerX_ load data and create texture object share with secWid_
slicerX_ = new slicerCanvas(this,secWid_);
```

and in the main window, I use `QHBoxLayout`:

```
hBox_ = new QHBoxLayout;
hBox_->addWidget(slicerX_);
hBox_->addWidget(secWid_);

centerWidget_->setLayout(hBox_);
```

It works right, but if I `addWidget` like this:

```
hBox_ = new QHBoxLayout;
hBox_->addWidget(secWid_);//first
hBox_->addWidget(slicerX_);//second

centerWidget_->setLayout(hBox_);
```

The `secWid_` will not paint anything, only `slicerX_` paints correctly. I am confused as to why.

Comment: By using `this`, do you actually need the address of the instance created for whatever reason?

Comment: @NanaOsaberima ,thanks,When I use '                                            secWid_ = new secCan(centerWidget_);
slicerX_ = new slicerCanvas(centerWidget_,secWid_);'it work correct.

Comment: Alright, you're welcome!